# Customizing AddThis Button Icon Graphic

Tags: javascript, html, sharing, addthis

I've got a bunch of AddThis sharing buttons that show up after someone subscribes to my e-mail list.

I'd like to add a sharing button for Google Plus, but it's not working.

For example, to put my own LinkedIn button, I use the following and it works like a charm:

```xml
<a class="addthis_button_linkedin"><img src="img/linkedin.png" width="64" height="64" alt="Share to LinkedIn"></a>
```

However, when I do the same for a custom Google+ button, two buttons appear.  Here is my markup:

```xml
<a class="addthis_button_google_plusone"><img src="img/googleplus.png" width="64" height="64" alt="Share to Google+"></a>
```

Has anyone run into this issue before?

If it's not supported on the API, is there a workaround?

I can use CSS to move the other icons to cover the small Google+ icon, but it looks sloppy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I rolled my own sharing buttons using PHP and HTML:

```
    <div class="sharing_buttons">
        <a class="google_plusone sharing" href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://YOUR_URL" target="_blank" title="Share on Google+"></a>
        <a class="facebook sharing" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://YOUR_URL" target="_blank"title="Share on Facebook"></a>
        <a class="twitter sharing" href="http://twitter.com/home?status=YOUR TWEET GOES HERE" target="_blank" title="Share on Twitter"></a>
        <a class="linkedin sharing" href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=
        <?php echo urlencode('YOUR_URL'); ?>
        &title=<?php echo urlencode('YOUR TITLE HERE'); ?>
        &summary=<?php echo urlencode('WRITE A SUMMARY HERE (SPACES WILL BE ENCODED)'); ?>
        &source=<?php echo urlencode('@4click'); ?>" target="_blank" title="Share on LinkedIn"></a>
        <a class="button_email sharing" href="mailto:?subject=YOUR SUBJECT&body=BODY OF THE EMAIL" target="_blank" title="Share via e-mail"></a>
    </div>
```

The icon graphics are added using CSS.  For example:

```
.google_plusone { background:url(../img/sharing_sprite.png) 0px 0px; }
```

The limitation of this solution is that you don't have the tracking features that AddThis offers, but I track my social shares using HootSuite, so it's not a big deal for me.

Answer (score 4):

You probably want to use the `addthis_button_google_plusone_share` button.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I wasn't having problems with adding the plusone code snippet.  I was already using the addthis_button_google_plusone_share button.  My problem was that I could not change the button graphic.  AddThis might have fixed it by now, but, at the time, you could specify any image for their other buttons (LinkedIn, Twitter, etc), but when you did that for PlusOne it would show your button image **as well as** the default button image (see first screen shot).